# Sum arrays in array variable

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have a little problem. Here is the code:

```
$arr = explode(',', $odluka);
$arr2 = array($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[3], $arr[4], $arr[5], $arr[6], $arr[7], $arr[8], $arr[9]);

while ($arrk = current($arr2)) {
    if ($arrk == '1') {
        $ark = key($arr2);
        //print_r($ark);
        //echo $arr2[$ark];
        $arop = explode(',', $utroseno);
        $aropk = array($arop[0], $arop[1], $arop[2], $arop[3], $arop[4], $arop[5], $arop[6], $arop[7], $arop[8], $arop[9]);

        $array = array($aropk[$ark]);

        print_r($array);


    }
    next($arr2);
}
```

Output of `$array` is

```
Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 5 ) Array ( [0] => 10 ) Array ( [0] => 4 ) Array ( [0] => 4 ) Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

How can I merge this values and sum them. I want sum of 1+5+10+4+4+1+1. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the data source?

Comment: Im trying to loop through row 'odluka' and look for 1. After that i want to loop through row 'utroseno' nad look for values on the same key as values 1 in row odluka.
https://i.imgur.com/bJ6NNcq.png

Answer (score 0):

1. declare a variable to store sum
2. iterate over array 
   -> add value to sum

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how to deal with your output array:

```
$data = [
    [1], [5], [10], [4]
];

$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($elem) { return $elem[0]; }, $data));

var_dump($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign them to another array and loop..you can just sum everything after explode. You just need one line of code for that:

```
array_sum(explode(',', $odluka));
```

Then you'll get the sum of all the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Not need using any array and loop.You are using only "array_sum ()" php building function.Like

```
<?php
    $foo[] = "12";
    $foo[] = 10;
    $foo[] = "bar";
    $foo[] = "summer";
    echo array_sum ($foo); //same as echo "22";
  ?>
```

For more information Read Php Manual [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
array_sum ($arr);
```